# WHILE EXIST NOT WORKING - To insert data to tables dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, while-loop, ssms

I am trying to insert data from txt files to existing tables dynamically. There is no error shown, it just doesn't stop running. I am not sure what the mistake I am doing in the while loop is.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#FILES') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FILES

CREATE TABLE #FILES
(
FileName VARCHAR(MAX),
DEPTH VARCHAR(MAX),
[FILE] VARCHAR(MAX)
)
 
INSERT INTO #FILES
EXEC master.dbo.xp_DirTree '\\Server1.newdevlab.local\SQLBackups_2012\Internal\Nimisha\',1,1
Select * from #FILES


DECLARE @FILENAME VARCHAR(MAX),@SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLENAME Varchar(12) 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #FILES)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
   SET @FILENAME = (SELECT TOP 1 FileName FROM #FILES)
   SET @TABLENAME =  'Buddy.' + right(@TABLENAME, len(@TABLENAME)-6)

   SET @SQL = N'BULK INSERT ' + @TABLENAME + '' +
              N' FROM ''\\Server1.newdevlab.local\SQLBackups_2012\Internal\Nimisha\' + @FILENAME +'''
   WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'');'

   PRINT @SQL
   EXEC(@SQL)
  
   DELETE FROM #FILES WHERE FileName = @FILENAME
END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      PRINT 'Failed processing : ' + @FILENAME
   END CATCH
END
```

Comment: This, in truth, looks like you're using the wrong tool for the job. This is something you should be doing *outside* of SQL Server with some kind of ETL layer.

Comment: If there is an error, eg. FileX fails, then the catch is executed without FileX being deleted from #FILES. The next iteration (while exists from #FILES) gets FileX which fails again, catch executed, FileX not deleted from #FILES etc etc..loop

Comment: If you would like to keep the code as is, just move `DELETE FROM #FILES WHERE FileName = @FILENAME` after the `END CATCH` (before the END of WHILE)

Comment: So is there any other methods?

Comment: I moved the delete statement after Catch block. Still it just gives a message:
Commands completed successfully. Completion time: 2022-10-04T11:40:54.7234602+01:00

Comment: If the only output is `Command(s) completed successfully.` then it sounds like `Select * from #FILES` is empty, meaning you're pointing in the wrong folder, or there are no files to process, or the only files to process can't be bulk inserted (but in that case I would expect at least a print message for the failure(s)).

Comment: A slightly better approach (if you refuse to move this process to something external to SQL Server, like PowerShell or C#) would be to use a cursor instead of while/delete. Then at least you can inspect the table after the process is finished. Did you confirm there are _valid_ rows in `#FILES`?

Comment: I did use a cursor and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to loop until you process all the records in the table, then I think you go with

1. get the count of records before the loop and loop until your counter exceeds the total number of records. I know I am not able to resolve your issue but giving a workaround. Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Same message with no insertions done. :   Message - Commands completed successfully.

Completion time: 2022-10-04T11:42:12.9594120+01:00

Answer (score 0):

```
USE xxxx


IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#FILES') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FILES

CREATE TABLE #FILES
(
FileName VARCHAR(100),
DEPTH VARCHAR(100),
[FILE] VARCHAR(MAX)
)
 
INSERT INTO #FILES
EXEC master.dbo.xp_DirTree '\\server.newdevlab.local\SQLBackups_2012\Internal\xxx\',1,1
Select * from #FILES


DECLARE @FILENAME VARCHAR(MAX) ,@SQLString VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLENAME Varchar(50) 
DECLARE file_cursor CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT FileName FROM #FILES
OPEN file_cursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM file_cursor
INTO @FileName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
  SET @TABLENAME = SUBSTRING(('Buddy.' + substring(@FILENAME,7, len(@FILENAME)-3)), 1 ,LEN(('Buddy.' + substring(@FILENAME,7, len(@FILENAME)-3)))-4)  
SET @SQLString = N'BULK INSERT ' + @TABLENAME + '' +
              N' FROM ''\\server.newdevlab.local\SQLBackups_2012\Internal\xxx\' + @FILENAME +'''
   WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'');'

  SELECT @SQLString
  EXEC(@SQLString)

  END TRY
  
  BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE(),ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_MESSAGE(),USER,GETDATE()
  END CATCH



  FETCH NEXT
  FROM file_cursor
  INTO @FileName
  END 
  CLOSE file_cursor
  DEALLOCATE file_cursor
```